# can abandoned go.microsoft.com/fwlink be found?

Tags: sql-server

I got an error from SQL Server with a link:

[https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=16.100.47008.0&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Discover+dependencies+DependencyWalker&LinkId=20476`](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=16.100.47008.0&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Discover+dependencies+DependencyWalker&LinkId=20476%60)

But the link just get forwarded to an useless `www.microsoft.com` advertising page regarding surface tablets and xboxes.

The error message comes from SSMS v18.11.1, on top of a SQL Server 11.0, so it's not very old.

Has Microsoft just abandoned all their professional users and removed the `go.microsoft.com` help pages?

It's not about this particular error message, but about finding the lost help pages in general.

Also, it's probably not about SQL Server alone, but there is no tag for "microsoft-stupid-things"

Comment: I don't think those links have error worked, as far as I can remember... Just Google the error. (Though SQL Server 11 (2012) is pretty old; it goes completely out of support in a few months.)

Comment: Please post the full error message. There is normally `Additional Information` which gives more detail

Comment: As I said, it's not about the actual error, but what happened to the link, that presumably did work when the sqlserver was shipped.

Comment: Unfortunately Microsoft has a habit of moving entire web sites without leaving a trail for old links. I’ve spent many hours correcting links on this site, on dba, and in my own blogs and articles. Click any link you find to connect.microsoft.com, for example, but they’ve done this to blogs and documentation, too. As an aside, @Larnu is right, it’s quite possible that link has never worked or, at best, linked to something far less than useful. Much better off googling the error message (or just cutting to the chase and searching here) than relying on those links.